# Not able to run Karma/Jasmine Tests on Bamboo CI

Tags: google-chrome, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, bamboo

Thanks in advance for looking into it. We are facing an issue with running our unit tests on Bamboo CI. We are using Karma-Chrome-Launcher (Have some issues with downloading PhantomJS in our restricted environment). In our local machine test does run fine without any issue.
However, in Bamboo CI, it tries to start chrome (I can see in taskbar that it has started chrome instance) but it never able to connect to Karma server and so is never able to run any test.
If I open chrome manually on Bamboo Agent, and enter localhost://9876, it will run test.

it tries three time and each time it throws 60000 second timeout error for not capturing chrome.

We have latest version of chrome(53.*) installed. 
Karma version is 0.13.15
Karma-chrome-launcher version is 0.2.3

Specific questions that I have - 
1) Is it feasible to run unit test on actual chrome browser on Bamboo?
2) If so, then any specific settings that we need to make in our config?
3) Any specific settings that we need to make on our Bamboo Server?

Answer (score 0):

Was able to run it. for those who might be struggling, below are the changes that I did - 
1) use no sand box version of browser via custom launcher config
2) upgraded karma to 0.13.22. version (0.13.15 had issues)

Comment: this is not accurate.

Comment: @dopatraman, could you please explain? I conveyed using which I could update. It seems very easy to say "it is not accurate", which doesn't help at all.

Comment: I changed the version to 0.13.22 and was getting the same problem

Comment: ok, I hope you understand that there are other factors as well. You might have a other dependencies that doesn't match with mine. So, instead of marking my comment as negative and not useful, you could have checked more about what else my code base had. great power (of negative voting) comes with great responsibility :).. and you could use it in better way.